How to display flowchart with different sections and swimlanes that can point to each other in markdown
Graph I am trying to recreate
I am trying to make a flowchart to be displayed in a page using markdown however I am having trouble getting it to look like the chart displayed above. I have tried using mermaid but it doesn't seem like a flowchart that is lined up like this is supported yet, at least as far as I have found so far. Am I missing something? I'd just like a direction to go in, it's preferred in my specific case to do it in markdown, if I can't however I am open to other ideas.
I tried something like this
flowchart TB
    subgraph TOP[ ]
    subgraph C
    direction LR
    C1{text} --> C2[text]
    C1 --> A4
    C2 --> B3
    end
    subgraph row2
    subgraph B
    direction LR
    B1[text] --> B2{text}
    B3[text]
    end
    end
    A2 -- yes --> D1[text]
    D1 --> D2{text}
    D2 --> A2
    D2 --> B1
    B2 --> D3[text]
    D3 --> A4
    D3 --> B2
    subgraph row1[ ]
    subgraph A
    direction LR
    A1[Triage] --> A2{text}
    A2 -- no --> A3[text]
    A4[text]
    A5[text] --> A4
    A5 --> B3
    end
    end
    end


expected the three sections to maybe line up but that isn't what happened

Note, I don't care too much about the stars

I think you would need swimlane diagram to do this to match the linked image. There are plans to support swimlanes, but I am not sure what the timeline is
